# PHP Loop Increment within a range

Tags: php

Have been off the PHP scene for a long time. I now need to adjust a Wordpress plugin and basically have the following :

```
    $count_of_stuff=10
    for ($i=0; $i<$count_of_stuff; $i++) {
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."numbers_table", array(
   "id" => $id,
        "num" => $number));
        $number++;
        }
```

Instead of using $number++ ( incrementing by 1 ) I need to pull from a list of numbers that arent necessarily sequential. ( 123,345,346,457,458,459 ). ( I will store these in a table )

Any thoughts/assistance? I am looking at the range option currently so may find an answer...

Thank you .

Comment: you could use `"num" => $number[$i]` referencing an array `$number = [123,345,346,457,458,459, ...];` defined before the loop (and drop the line with `$number++`)

Comment: Thank you will try when back at desk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
 $custom_array=array(123,345,346,457,458,459);  
 $count_of_stuff=6;
 for($i=0; $i<$count_of_stuff; $i++) 
 {
 $number=$custom_array[$i];
 $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."numbers_table", array("id" => $id,"num" => $number));
 
 }
```